# Validate the user using Siteminder WebAgent SSO

Tags: java, single-sign-on, siteminder

i want to implement SSO in an application for that i have a SiteMinder policy server at the application which provide the login (say application 1) and also have installed the Siteminder webagent on the server of other application which am going to login through SSO (say application 2). This siteminder thing is already done by some other team. Now i want to get the siteminder session and from that session i want the HTTP_SM_USER this is all with the help of WebAgent. After getting the user i want to validate the user against the DB of 2nd application. Can anyone guide me how can i proceed with this work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SM agent usually adds an HTTP header with the user ID to the incoming request. You can inspect this header in your code to determine the user.  Note that this header does not come from the browser, the SM agent inserts it before the request is handed to your application.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. You mean to say that i have to write a JSP code which will run on my Serevr on which the web agent is installed, and in that code i have to inspect the header for user information and then validate the user..

Comment: I am not familiar with JSP, but your understanding is correct. You need to implement some logic on the web server to inspect the incoming HTTP header set by the SiteMinder agent. The team that set up the agent should tell you the exact header name, because it is configured on the agent.

Comment: JSP is just a java code that runs on servers like PHP or ASP. Well thanks for the support i will implement the code and try.....

Comment: One often overlooked point: you need to check for each request that either your user id in session is empty (first access of the user) or that the userid in the SM header is the same as the userid in your session.